# Puppeteer.net: cant figure out the selector

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I am using puppeteer in trying to find the selector for a login page.
the login html is:

```
<form action="/login?app=LM&var=au" method="POST" name="login-form" id="login-form">
           
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="BQ2YoR3d-5P__6b5HfqlVOjv8YgTypKV92XA" />
            
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="text" name="username" id="login-form-username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <input type="password" name="password" id="login-form-password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

I tried #submit, #login-form-submit and several others for the selector. what would the selector for the login button be as there is no ID name?

i am using ClickAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either give your submit button an id property and use the `#submit` selector you previously tried:

```
<button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
```

Or use `form button[type=submit]` as selector.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant add an ID property as it is a third party website, but the selector worked fine. Thanks a lot